# Error loading hubs

Tags: javascript, signalr

I am creating chat application using signalR. I have added signalr.js 1.0.1.
I have created signalr hub in global.asax when application strarts like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration() { EnableCrossDomain = true });
```

But my problem is its showing me error like below sometimes.

```
Uncaught Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/hubs'></script>.
```

**EDIT:**
I have added all files for signalr dynamically

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    //add all js files for signalR chat dynamically to body
    function SetSignalRJs() {
        var fileref = document.createElement('script');
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", "Include/JS/JqueryPlugin/SignalR/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.js");

        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    }
    function SetHub() {
        var fileref = document.createElement('script');
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", "signalr/hubs");
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    }
    function SetChatJs() {
        var fileref = document.createElement('script');
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", "Include/JS/CollectiveIntelligence/ChatApplication.js");
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    }

    //apply timeout for all js files
    setTimeout(SetSignalRJs, 1000);
    setTimeout(SetHub, 5000);
    setTimeout(SetChatJs, 6000);
```

Comment: well did you include the `/signalr/hubs` on your page html? please post the code of your html and javascript as well

Comment: try updating your version of signalR first, is that an option ?

Comment: the error i can see for sometimes only. I can not understand the reason for it.

Comment: The error comes if SetChatJS called before SetHub. But i have applied setTimeout which donot work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load in your scripts dynamically you should use a script loader.
For a quick and simple solution you can try and use

http://headjs.com/

For a more robust solution with dependency management and more, it's worth investigating:

http://requirejs.org/

Comment: I have used head.js and now its working perfect. No need to use setTimeOut. Thanks for your suggetion.